# Renaming a Cocoapods dependency

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoapods

I'm looking for a way to rename a Cocoapods dependency after it's been downloaded, but before the app is compiled.

In my specific use case, I have a dependency which is hardcoded to refer to the [ZipZap framework](https://github.com/pixelglow/ZipZap). However, in the podspec it is referred to as "zipzap" (lowercase), resulting in it being compiled to zipzap.framework rather than ZipZap.framework and causing a dyld crash on app launch:

```
dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/ZipZap.framework/ZipZap
  Referenced from: /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/bla/bla
  Reason: image not found
```

I could of course contact the maintainers and ask them to rename their dependency, but given that it's not been maintained in 3yrs, I'm not holding out hope...

Instead, it would be far easier to just rename the dependency with either a `pre_install` or `post_install` hook in my Podfile (like I do for other build settings), but I can't really see any examples of actually renaming a dependency, and my Ruby is pretty rusty/nonexistent.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution to this:

1. I copied the `zipzap.podspec.json` file from the zipzap Github repo onto my local machine (project folder).
2. I manually edited the podspec file and changed the name (and also the podspec.json file for good measure)
3. I updated my Podfile to refer to the dependency in its new name, linked to my local copy of the Podfile:

```
pod 'ZipZap', :podspec => 'path/to/ZipZap.podspec.json'
```

4. Run `pod install` and the local Podspec version will now be used (which still points to get the code from the remote repo).

It's an ugly workaround, but it works!

Comment: Worked for me, ***thank you*** ! Had this issue while trying to use Apple's iOS 16 Swift Charts, had a pod named Charts so the compiler could not figure out what `import Charts` meant